# Overriding Django model save method with image resizing

Tags: django

The below code successfully override the save method

```
class News(models.Model):
   ...........
  photo=models.ImageField()

    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
        img1 = Image.open(self.image1.path)
    
        if img1.height > 400 or img1.width > 400:
            output_size = (400,400)
            img1.thumbnail(output_size)
            img1.save(self.image1.path)
```

But after `super().save()` code, image is being opened and saved. Is it an efficient method? how its possible to reopen image after saving .

Comment: This way of resizing works and isn't inefficient. Opening an image to resize it and then save it is plenty quick so long as the image isn't huge. Is that what you're asking? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: You seem to be asking about the solution to your problem rather than the problem, why do you need to update the image every time the model is saved instead of when something has changed within it?